# React Native Using 3rd Party Native SDKs

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile

We're in the planning phase for an upcoming project and would love some insight on whether React Native would be appropriate for development.

One of the requirements is integrating a 3rd party native SDK for both Android and iOS. The provider offers both Android and iOS SDKs but has stated they only provide native SDKs and thus believe a hybrid app would not work.

Can React Native use these 3rd party SDKs that have been built for Android and iOS?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Of course. If you look at any of the open source RN libraries which use native features, you can see how they create RN bridge function which are available in your RN JS.